# PHP show used internal function in a script

Tags: php, function

Is there a way how I can find out what internal PHP function was used in a script?

```
<?php
        echo "Hi";
        $x = substr("hello",3);
```

Goal is to get: echo, substr

get_defined_functions shows all global available but how I could find out only the used one inside a script?

To parse the file is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to achieve? *Why* do you want to know this information? If we know what you're looking for we may be able to better suggest a method to get the result you need.

Comment: You need a profiler. xDebug provides a good one.

Comment: I have got a encoded script and I wish to know what function it uses before I put them on our production server.

Comment: [Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20091030071047/http://talk.cmyweb.net/talks/regular-expression/) is some regex approach to parse variable names.  Hope it helps to a function name extractor.

Answer (score 1):

You may use XDebug profiler to see, what functions were executed in your scripts and how many times. But it will gather all function executions (system and custom), and I don't remember can it be filtered somehow.

Comment: @max It look's Xdebug won't show any if the file is ioncubed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to burst your bubble, but parsing is probably your best bet. You wont catch function calls in eval'd code though - `eval`, `call_user_func` etc.

I am curious though why you would want to do this. Can you describe your use case?